# How to access this paragraph using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation

I've this code into my form:

```
    <li id="form-item_title">
        <label class="desc">Title</label>
        <div>
        <select id="title" class="field select" style="">
                <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <p class="error_descr"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="form-item_country">
        <label class="desc">Country</label>
        <div>
        <select id="country" class="field select" style="">
                <option value="">...</option>
        </select>
        <p class="error_descr"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

All I need is adding some content to a specific `error_descr` paragraph. I did this but it's not working:

```
jQuery('li#form-item_title p.error_descr').html("Required");
jQuery('li#form-item_title p.error_descr').show();
```

How to do that?

Comment: It seems to work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/PByYw/ (Note, if by *specific* you mean only element with that class, you have to use a more specific selector like an `id` selector`.)

Comment: you have 2 elements use same ID.. its forbidden

Comment: just an error when coping to stackoverflow but this is still not working...

Comment: But it does "work" with your updated markup: http://jsfiddle.net/PByYw/1/ Can you define more precisely "not working"?

Comment: If you look more you'll see the <p class="error_descr"></p> is into a DIV and the whole is wrapped in the <li> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('li#form-item_title p.error_descr').html("Required").show();
```

Notice you can chain your function calls to avoid using the same selector multiple times.

You can also select the `error_descr` elements by their association with the form element they are siblings with:

```
jQuery('#title').on('change', function () {
    jQuery(this).siblings('.error_descr').html('Required').show();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xnVzs/

**UPDATE**

Also you can improve the performance of your selectors by doing this:

```
jQuery('#form-item_title').find('.error_descr').html("Required").show();
```

It generally takes more time to select an element if you add the tag name.

Comment: Also, just an aside, `li#form-item_title-1` is not necessary, `#form-item_title-1` is good enough.

Comment: @StephaneKouakou - It does seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/PByYw/1/ Can you provide more information on what "it does not work" means?

Comment: @StephaneKouakou I changed the selector to `.siblings()` and it works in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xnVzs/

Comment: If you look more you'll see the <p class="error_descr"></p> is into a DIV and the whole is wrapped in the <li> tag

Comment: @StephaneKouakou Yeah but the `<select>` inputs are both siblings of the `.error_desc` paragraph elements. So relatively `.siblings()` will select the paragraph element from the `<select>` element. And selecting `$('#form-item_title').find('.error_desc')` works fine. Notice I changed `.children()` to `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `form-item_title` to a class—an `id` has to be unique.

```
$("li.form-item_title p")
    .text("Required")
    .show();
```

And you don't necessarily need the additional class in the selector since there's only one `p` in the `li`.

Also, always remember to wrap your DOM-manipulative Javascript in a DOM-ready listener. jQuery has this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

or:

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `id`.

`id` is meant to be unique, so only *one* element can have a single `id`. If you want a property that can group many elements, try `class`.

```
var paragraph = jQuery('p.error_descr').eq(1);

paragraph.html("Required");
paragraph.show();
```

`.eq(1)` selects the second element matching that selector.

Comment: You don't even need to cache the selector--just chain the functions.

Comment: What did you change in your code? Also, try my edited code. It might work.

Comment: If you look more you'll see the <p class="error_descr"></p> is into a DIV and the whole is wrapped in the <li> tag

Comment: You don't need to worry about the hierarchy. As long as your `<p>` tags with that class do one thing, you can just look specifically for them.